# html select statement with js and php not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to to use html select and basing on the selected value display the mysql query value. 
I pick the selected value by id using javascript and their after convert them to php variables as demostrated below

I then use a comparison statement to evaluate the php variable and if true go ahead echo the db query result. However the if statement on the php script seems not to be working and doesnt return or echo anything

```
        //HTML FORM select
    <form method="post" action="" name="myform">
          <th style="width:3%;" >MOH
            <select name="moh" id="myselect" onchange="javascript: form.submit();">        
              <option id="4" value="received_moh_day1">Day 1</option>
              <option id="5" value= "received_moh_day2">Day 2</option>
              <option id="6" value= "received_moh_day1_and_2">Day 1 and 2</option>
            </select> 
          </th>
        </form>
          <script type="text/javascript">

            var jvalue_moh_1 = document.getElementById('4').value;
            var jvalue_moh_2 = document.getElementById('5').value;
            var jvalue_moh_3 = document.getElementById('6').value;
            //document.getElementById('personlist').value=Person_ID;         
          </script>

         <script type="text/javascript">   
         //Convert Javascript variable to php variable             
           <?php 

           $moh1 = "<script>document.write(jvalue_moh_1)</script>";
           $moh2 = "<script>document.write(jvalue_moh_2)</script>";
           $moh3 = "<script>document.write(jvalue_moh_3)</script>";
           //$moh = "<script>document.write(jvalue2)</script>" ;
           ?>   
         </script>        

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php endif; ?>
        <?php 


        $i=1;
            if ($data && $_GET['log'] == 'ATTNSC')  {
              print_r($moe1);
              foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                  //print_r($moe3);
                  if($moe3 == 'received_moe_day1_and_2'){ 
                   echo "<td class='align-td' id='received_moe_day1_and_2_td".$i."'>".$value['received_moe_day1_and_2']."</td>";
                   }
                  elseif ($moe2 == 'received_moe_day2'){

                   echo "<td class='align-td' id='received_moe_day1_and_2_td".$i."'>".$value['received_moe_day2']."</td>";
                   }
                  elseif ($moe1 == 'received_moe_day1'){
                    echo "<td class='align-td' id='received_moe_day1_td".$i."'>".$value['received_moe_day1']."</td>";
                  }

                  elseif ($moh3 == 'received_moh_day1_and_2'){    
                   echo "<td class='align-td' id='received_moh_day1_and_2_td".$i."'>".$value['received_moh_day1_and_2']."</td>";
                   }
                  elseif ($moh2 == 'received_moh_day2'){

                   echo "<td class='align-td' id='received_moh_day1_and_2_td".$i."'>".$value['received_moh_day2']."</td>";
                   }
                  elseif ($moh1 == 'received_moh_day1') {
                    echo "<td class='align-td' id='received_moh_day1_td".$i."'>".$value['received_moh_day1']."</td>";

                  }



                $i++;
              }
            }else{

        ?>
```

Comment: Activity with `home_page` name available in code?

Comment: Is 'home_page' the name of your class? That is the file that ends in .java? Most likely your class name is HomePage and your layout file is home_page. You need to point it towards the class not the layout file

Comment: btw, where is your package name in `application` tag?

Comment: Yes , Where is your base package

Comment: As far I know, there's no class that has lowercase name at the first letter.